# display: table - 1st column has set width, 2nd col fit to content, 3rd col has set width, 4th col take up the remainder

Tags: html, css, styling, css-tables, tablerow

I'm probably missing something obvious, but I can't figure this out.

I have a table taking up 100% of its container width.  The first and third columns have set widths.  I'd like the second column to be fit to its content (ideally with a max width) and the fourth column to take up the remaining space.

The third and fourth are actually input boxes, so I don't care about whether the text wraps in this example.  (I used text here because it's easier to see what's going on.  Based on local testing, I don't think it makes a difference.)

Fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/vgrdLp32/**

```css
.table-container {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.table-row {
    display: table-row;
}
.table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 2px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255, 102, 102, .2);
}
.col1 {
    width: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 51, 153, .2);
}
.col2 {
    width: auto; /* ????? */
    background-color: rgba(51, 102, 255, .2);
}
.col3 {
    width: 135px;
    background-color: rgba(153, 102, 255, .2);
}
.col4 {
    background-color: rgba(204, 0, 204, .2);
}
* {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', Arial;
}
```

```html
<link  href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:regular,italic,bold,bolditalic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<div class="table-container">
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell col1"></div>
        <div class="table-cell col2">plz autosize me!</div>
        <div class="table-cell col3">i have a set width</div>
        <div class="table-cell col4">make me take up the rest</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell col1"></div>
        <div class="table-cell col2">i hope</div>
        <div class="table-cell col3">that i will never</div>
        <div class="table-cell col4">let you down</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell col1"></div>
        <div class="table-cell col2">i know</div>
        <div class="table-cell col3">that this</div>
        <div class="table-cell col4">could be more than</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell col1"></div>
        <div class="table-cell col2">just flashing</div>
        <div class="table-cell col3">lights and sounds</div>
        <div class="table-cell col4">can we pick you off the ground</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you can get away without supporting IE9, flexbox is the way to go here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the fourth column to be `width: 100%`, so it will squeeze all the non-width columns into their content size.

Also, remember to remove the `table-layout: fixed`, otherwise it will make the table assume the measurements of the first row's columns to every other row...

```css
.table-container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.table-row {
    display: table-row;
}
.table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 2px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255, 102, 102, .2);
}
.col1 {
    width: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 51, 153, .2);
}
.col2 {
    background-color: rgba(51, 102, 255, .2);
}
.col3 {
    width: 135px;
    background-color: rgba(153, 102, 255, .2);
}
.col4 {
  width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(204, 0, 204, .2);
}
* {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', Arial;
}
```

```html
<link  href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:regular,italic,bold,bolditalic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<div class="table-container">
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell col1"></div>
        <div class="table-cell col2">plz autosize me!</div>
        <div class="table-cell col3">i have a set width</div>
        <div class="table-cell col4">make me take up the rest</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell col1"></div>
        <div class="table-cell col2">i hope</div>
        <div class="table-cell col3">that i will never</div>
        <div class="table-cell col4">let you down</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell col1"></div>
        <div class="table-cell col2">i know</div>
        <div class="table-cell col3">that this</div>
        <div class="table-cell col4">could be more than</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="table-cell col1"></div>
        <div class="table-cell col2">just flashing</div>
        <div class="table-cell col3">lights and sounds</div>
        <div class="table-cell col4">can we pick you off the ground</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want to keep it from wrapping, you could add `white-space:nowrap` to the `.table-row` class.

Comment: Thanks so much, both of you!  In [**my solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/vgrdLp32/6/), I got rid of the `table-layout: fixed` and added `width: 100%` to the 4th column.  To preserve the specified widths of the 1st and 3rd columns, I had to change the `width` to `min-width`.  For the 2nd column, I added `white-space: nowrap` and (for my own purposes) I specified a `min-width` and `max-width`, then set `overflow: hidden` and `text-overflow: ellipsis`.

Answer (score 1):

What you want exactly can't be done with CSS alone - tables are not flexible enough for that. Either you give them a "natural" layout (width of all cells based on their contents) or a fixed layout (widths as specified). So you can't give one column a fixed width and another column a natural width.

However, if you're willing to use some JavaScript, It's not difficult to keep the fixed layout and make one column as wide as its contents - just calculate what the contents actually are, and set the width "hardcoded" to that value.
I do this by creating an invisible element that I copy all the contents to and remembering the max width.

```
const table = document.getElementsByClassName("table-container")[0];
const wdiv = document.getElementById('widthtest');
var width2 = 0;
const rows = table.children;
for (var row = 0; row<rows.length; ++row) {
    const cells = rows[row].children;
    if (cells!=undefined && cells.length>=4) {
        wdiv.textContent = cells[1].textContent;
        width2 = Math.max(width2, wdiv.clientWidth);
    }
}
rows[0].children[1].style.width = width2+'px';
```

See [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/vgrdLp32/5/).

Comment: Whoa, this looks great!!  I ended up getting close enough to what I wanted with some changes suggested below plus some `min-width`s and `max-width`s for that tricky column (solution [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/vgrdLp32/6/)) but this is an awesome solution.  `textContent` is super useful; I've used it for breadcrumbs and similar.  Wish I could choose two answers!